# Configuring QGIS Pop Up like in WMS with QGIS2WEB

Tags: qgis, popup

I need a QGIS pop up window like in the WEB Version of QGIS2WEB plugin, when I click on a object to get information of the feature.

The pop up I want in QGIS is like in this photo.

[image: Pop up Window in WMS]

Answer (score 1):

It is easy, you must include the popup fields which you want to visualize (header label).
When all is ready, click the button "Update preview" and you could watch the popup from the feature.
Here you have an image in case you need more help.

[image: popup]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you didn't understand me. I want in QGIS program the pop up window to look like that in WMS(like in picture), also I want that when I click ower an objekt in QGIS to have the information window the same like in WMS using Qgis2WEB.